# Drag and Drop Java GUI

Tags: java

I am looking to create a GUI in Java, where I place controls or elements on a left pane and can drag them onto a designer pane, similar to creating a model in Visio.

The current one I'm looking at is [JGraphX](http://www.jgraph.com/jgraph.html), it allows you to create graphs etc.

Are there any other projects out there that support this, or tools etc.

Answer (score 13):

While it seems to be a good idea at first glance to create a UI with drag and drop, I always found that the UI editors made me much less productive than writing the code by hand:

1. The property editor for UI elements always shows 150 properties which I don't need and I have to scroll every time to get the one I always change.
2. Changing properties needs too many clicks with the mouse (and sometimes the aim of a world class StarCraft player)
3. There is no way to reuse common things like colors, texts, initialization
4. The resulting code it a large, unreadable mess without structure
5. There is no code completion

Answer (score 5):

[WindowBuilder](http://code.google.com/javadevtools/wbpro/) (Swing, SWT, GWT etc.) was a commercial product before Instantiatons was acquired by Google and has been proposed as a new project to the Eclipse Foundation. While you'll certainly always have the greatest flexibility with hand coding (like [Aaron suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5217904/drag-and-drop-java-gui/5218031#5218031) in his answer) I have had a lot of great experience with the tool.

The project is in [Eclipse Incubation](http://www.eclipse.org/proposals/tools.windowbuilder/) currently, but has been used in production for years. If you want to create a GUI with Drag'n'Drop you should definitely have a look at WindowBuilder.

Answer (score 2):

There are few GUI builders available.

--> [Netbeans](http://netbeans.org/features/java/swing.html)

--> [SpeedJG](http://www.wsoftware.de/SpeedJG/)

--> [IntelliJIdea](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/)

--> [Eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/vep/)

Answer (score 1):

JGraphx has a nice example called editor that does exactly what you are trying to accomplish. Just look in the downloaded zip file in the /examples/com/mxgraph/examples/swing/editor - there is everything you need.

Alternatively you might want to use JUNG http://jung.sourceforge.net/. For this one see the following demo - it might give you some clues: http://jung.sourceforge.net/applet/grapheditordemo.html

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps look at the [Eclipse Modelling Framework](http://www.eclipse.org/modeling/emf/).  It is a good starting point for a modeling tool.